# Complete AWS Codestar project as code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codestar

Is it possible to build a complete AWS Codestar project from code?

Codestar comes with a selection of project templates in the console GUI, I would like to start with templates as code, so everything can be under config management.

Comment: Do you want to write your own CodeStar template? Or take an existing on and track the entire template (including the deployment stacks) that CodeStar uses?

Comment: It should be possible to create a new template from scratch and have that in a repo. Starting a bespoke project from an existing template is not an option for a large organisation.

Comment: Okay. I asked for something similar. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/issues/47 It was kind of a major drawback for my team too. I opened an internal issue for this to be resolved, but for the meantime, a possible work around is to launch the CodeStar project and then copy out the CF template and launch it on your own by hand.

Answer (score 1):

*To the mods, I will update this answer from a sketchy PR to more refined solution as one emerges*

Not really a perfect answer, but I created a CF template that can deploy a CodeStar project. You could in theory attach multiple projects to the same Git repo (be it CodeCommit or GitHub).

See my [pull request](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/pull/55/files). If it is buggy, let me know so I can fix it.

Comment: I have not been able to get CloudFormation to create a CodeStar project. The web console for CF throws a 'CodeStar Projects can only be created from the CodeStar console' error. Any news on CF codification ability of CodeStar projects?